# Java Concurrency Synchronized not working

Tags: java, concurrency

Concurrency is not working as expected.

```
class Counter {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        new Thread(() -> counter.increment()).start();
        new Thread(() -> counter.decrement()).start();
        System.out.println(counter.value());
    }
}
```

This one prints 1 instead of 0. I copied this example from Oracle tutorial, I'm not sure where I'm wrong.

Comment: Since you don't join the Threads, you may not safely assume that any or all of your Threads have yet finished, nor even started.

Comment: @GyroGearless so it will be necessary to call join() method everytime? I'm kinda new to this in java. Thank you!

Comment: @kalasag only when you need their final result. Think about it; the purpose of the threads is to run concurrently, so potentially not having finished at that point, is exactly what you ask for. Of course, it doesn’t have to be that low level. Consider, e.g. `Counter counter = new Counter(); Executor newThread = r -> new Thread(r).start(); CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> counter.increment(), newThread). thenAcceptBoth(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> counter.decrement(), newThread), (x,y) -> System.out.println(counter.value()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use join on threads before getting results from them.
Also you need to use synchronize on each method which will be used in async Thread, in this example its increment and decrement method.

I made an example which shows what happens without synchronized added to methods

```
class Counter {
    private int c = 0;

    public void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public int value() {
        return c;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            Counter counter = new Counter();
            List<Thread> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                list.add(new Thread(counter::increment));
                list.add(new Thread(counter::decrement));
            }

            for (Thread item : list) {
                item.start();
            }
            System.out.println("Results");
            System.out.println(counter.value());
            System.out.println(counter.value());
            System.out.println(counter.value());
            System.out.println(counter.value());
            System.out.println(counter.value());

            for (Thread item : list) {
                item.join();
            }

            System.out.println("Results after join");
            System.out.println(counter.value());
        }
    }
}
```

I did run it a few times and sometimes the results where -3 even after using join

Answer (score 0):

You don't wait for your threads to finish. So you have the chance, that none, both or just one threads ran and so your result could be -1, 0 or 1. You should use join() to wait for your threads to finish.

```
public void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> counter.increment());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> counter.decrement());
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join(); // waits for t1 to end processing
    t2.join(); // waits for t2 to end processing
    System.out.println(counter.value());
}
```

You can also remove synchronized from value() because it is not used in any asynchronous process anymore.

Comment: If i used join(), would synchronized be necessary in the method modifier?

Comment: In increment() and decrement(), yes. But not in value() since the method is not used in any asynchronous process.

Answer (score 0):

Execution thread in your main function are not linked to your process. Thread-2 could run before the Thread-1, they could both run after your print statement, and vice versa. Try to re-execute your main different times and print also the thread in run function. This can help you to understand better. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Counter counter = new Counter();

    new Thread(() -> {
        counter.increment();
        System.out.println("Thread-1 increment");
    }).start();
    new Thread(() -> {
        counter.decrement();
        System.out.println("Thread-2 decrement");
    }).start();
    System.out.println(counter.value());
}
```

Comment: Yes, quite understand that it actually gives not just only 1 value, the thing I'm thinking is the necessity of synchronize in the method modifier

Comment: Syncronize allows to wait the execution before to finish at "object/class level", it does not guarantee that the threads go in a particular sequence. For example n your case: T1 wants to execute increment of counter object and T2 wants to execute decrement of the same counter object. When a thread executes a synchronized method of the object, all other threads which want to execute a sync methods of the same object wait that the thread before completes its execution. Your first case is T1 executes, T2 waits but println executes "because it's not sync" and the Thread-2 executes when T1 finished